# Capture and split TAP Output/Result

Tags: perl, parsing, tap

i want to catch the TAP output of my scripts, to write it with some additional information into an openoffice document for my collegues, and as normal TAP-Output for me into the console. This has to be done inside(!) my script.

I'll guess TAP::Parser is the way i should go, right? I don't know how, and i cant find an simple example. If i got a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 2;

is( 1 + 1, 2, "one plus one is two" );
#missing code to capture the result of the test above

is( 1 + 1, 11, "one plus one is more than two" );
#missing code to capture the result of the test above
```

How can i get the results of each test? To create a openoffice document is not the problem.

Is TAP::Parser the right way to do what i want?

Thx

roli

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to capture the output is with [the `--archive` flag to prove](https://metacpan.org/module/prove#OPTIONS).  This will save the test suite output in a tarball along with a summary of the results.  You should also use the `--merge` flag so STDERR is captured.

```
$ prove --archive test_out.tgz --merge my_test.pl
my_test.pl .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=3,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.01 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: PASS

TAP Archive created at /home/you/test_out.tgz
```

Once you have that you can read it back in at your leisure, reparse it with TAP::Parser and do what you like with it.

```
use TAP::Parser;

my $tap_file = shift;
open my $tap_fh, $tap_file or die $!;

# Can't just pass in the .t file, it will try to execute it.
my $parser = TAP::Parser->new({
    source => $tap_fh
});

while ( my $result = $parser->next ) {
    # do whatever you like with the $result, like print it back out
    print $result->as_string, "\n";
}
```

If for some reason you can't/won't use prove, you can insert capture code into your script.  I would *HIGHLY RECOMMEND AGAINST THIS* as you have to do it for every test script, it must be hard coded into the test which makes them less useful for normal testing (ie. running the test via prove or Test::Harness (which prove is just a wrapper around)).  You also have to do some fancy footwork to make sure you capture the complete output of the test, any warnings going to STDERR or STDOUT, not just the test output.

So before I explain that, since you're running the test program by hand (which you shouldn't be) here's how you do it using the bash shell.

```
perl my_test.pl > test.out 2>&1
```

If that works for you, use that.  It's not worth getting into hard coding it into the script.

You still have to process test.out using something like the TAP::Harness script above to get meaning out of it, but that will capture the complete output of the program.  You can do this in one step, again with shell redirection.

```
perl my_test.pl 2>&1 | tap2oo
```

Where tap2oo is your program which translates TAP to an Open Office document.

Comment: THX, i'll see if i can solve my problem with this tip. I'll guess there is no (easy) way to capture the TAP output directly inside my script? To run the test,

Comment: By "the script" do you mean the test itself? Yes, you can change where the test output goes with the [output methods of Test::Builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Builder#Output). The Test::Builder object is accessible via [Test::More->builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::More#Extending-and-Embedding-Test::More). Problem is A) this won't capture warnings and other non-test output and B) you have to do this in every test program which is cumbersome.

Comment: By "the script" should be the replacement for "#missing code to capture the result of the test above" as i wrote in the example of my initial posting. It might be cumbersome, but actualy i don't see a other solution, so i'll see if Test::Builder can help me catching the TAP.

Comment: @roli My answer contains another solution using `prove --archive --merge` to run the tests.  If there's a reason you can't run the tests with prove (which is just a wrapper around TAP::Parser) you should add to the original post so we can work with that.  You really don't want to be hard coding this in every test.  [Trust me, I know what I'm talking about](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Builder#AUTHORS).

Comment: Actual i don't see how i could manage to use prove, everything has to happen inside the .pl script

Comment: @roli When you say ".pl script", do you mean the `.t` script?  Or is this some other script you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @roli I'm not sure what you mean by "contains the tests" but you have to use something to *run the tests* and then *parse the TAP output*.  prove does that.  Use `prove --archive ...` to run the tests and it will capture the output.

Comment: the code which i posted initial (as example) is saved as my_test.pl. I invoke this with"perl my_test.pl"

Comment: @roli If you're invoking the test by hand and reading the output by eye you're missing a critical element of testing in Perl. You should run test files with another program that interprets the TAP output for you. When you run "make test" on a Perl module that's what happens. [prove](http://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html) is such a thing, it's a command line version of [Test::Harness](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Harness). Run `prove my_test.pl` to get an idea. prove can run a whole directory full of test files and interpret the output. That's why you don't have to capture inside the script.

Comment: that's the reason for my initial Question how to capture the TAP results. I'm doing web tests with selenium. I'm the technikal guy in the team. I want to capture the TAP results to include them in the odt document, which is created during the test for the domain experts. My testscript is creating screenshots ... and i want to write the TAP result right next to the corrospndending screenshot. The example i provided was quite simple, but i thought i was sufficient the explain how to capture the result.

Comment: @roli If my_test.pl contains selenium tests, this shouldn't change things. No matter what the test is doing, you can still run it with prove. That is the beauty of TAP, it makes test programs universal. Instead of running `perl my_test.pl` run `prove --archive test_out.tgz --merge my_test.pl`.  The test will run, your users will get a nice test summary (use `-v` if they want to see the raw TAP), your screenshots will be saved along with a tarball of the TAP results.  If you want to make it more convenient, write a wrapper around prove that unpacks the tarball.

Comment: The code above dose only work on ".t" files, not an the compressed archive directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [plugin for App::Prove](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aProve#PLUGINS). A good reference/starting point is the [Test::Pretty](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-Pretty).