# Extract and Format Information from TAP Archive

Tags: perl, tap

What I like to do:

I am using [Rex](https://metacpan.org/module/Rex) to remotely call tests at servers. I remotely execute the tests with a call the the local `prove`. I want to gather all the information about the testruns at the different servers at one place. To achieve this I run the tests with `prove -a` (and maybe also with `--merge` for capturing `STDERR`) to create an archive (`.tgz`). I then download this archive again with `Rex` to the controlling server. I think this is quite a good plan so far...

My problem now is that I find a lot of hints on creating such a TAP-archive, but none of how I can actually read this archive. Sure, I could open and process it somehow with `Archive::Tar` or parse it manually with `TAP::Parser` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781443/capture-and-split-tap-output-result) by Schwern. But knowing that there are formatters like `TAP::Formatter::HTML` or `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` (e.g. for Jenkins) I think there must be a way of using those tools directly on a TAP-archive? When I look up the docs I only find hints on how to use this stuff with `prove` to format tests while running them. But I need to use this formatters on the archive, I have been running `prove` already remotely...

So far about the context. **My question in short is:** How can I use the Perl-TAP-Tools to format TAP coming from a TAP-archive produced by prove?

I am thankful for any little hints. Also if you see a problem in my approach in general.

Comment: Hmmm... is it that I need to use a source handler for prove using the --source option?

Comment: How about extracting the archive then using TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File on the output files

Comment: You mean by extracting the archive manually, parse the meta.yml and then add each TAP-file as a source handler? This is quite some work. Is it really that an archive is a read-only dead-end? Why do I then actually want to create such an archive. Then it would be much easier to call `prove --merge > results.tab` and then use this one file as a source. But this is weird... why does prove have an option to create archives if nobody can read them without a lot of extra coding. I really hoped there is a library which can handle archives.

Comment: Slide 30 in this presentation tells me, that there must be a way: http://de.slideshare.net/spurkis/tapharness-friends

Comment: Maybe there is a way of telling TAP::Parser to use some output formatters... I will look in this direction.

Comment: Seems like Smolder is a tool worth looking for. As far as I can tell now, it processes TAP-archives and displays them nicely. This does not answer my question, but maybe is a way to make it obsolete. https://metacpan.org/module/Smolder

Comment: last upload of Smolder was 2009 -_-

Comment: I found some code in Smolder which is doing this in `lib/Smolder/DB/SmokeReport.pm`. As far as I can tell you have to mix up some `TAP::Harness` stuff with a call to `aggregator_from_archive` from `TAP::Harness::Archive`. But wow... this is not easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renée provided a working solution here: http://www.perl-community.de/bat/poard/thread/18420 (German)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use TAP::Harness::Archive;
use TAP::Harness;
use TAP::Formatter::HTML;

my $formatter = TAP::Formatter::HTML->new;

my $harness   = TAP::Harness->new({ formatter => $formatter });

$formatter->really_quiet(1);
$formatter->prepare;

my $session;
my $aggregator = TAP::Harness::Archive->aggregator_from_archive({ 
    archive          => '/must/be/the/complete/path/to/test.tar.gz',
    parser_callbacks => {
        ALL => sub {
            $session->result( $_[0] );
        },
    },
    made_parser_callback => sub {
        $session = $formatter->open_test( $_[1], $_[0] );
    }
});

$aggregator->start;
$aggregator->stop;

$formatter->summary($aggregator);
```

Tanks a lot! I hope this will help some others too. It seems like this knowledge is not very wide spread yet.

I have made a module to pack this solution in a nice interface: https://metacpan.org/module/Convert::TAP::Archive

So from now on you can just type this:

```
use Convert::TAP::Archive qw(convert_from_taparchive);

my $html = convert_from_taparchive(
               '/must/be/the/complete/path/to/test.tar.gz',
               'TAP::Formatter::HTML',
           );
```

The problem with the output is mentioned in the docs. Please provide patches or comments if you know how to fix this (minor) issue. E.g. here: https://github.com/borisdaeppen/Convert-TAP-Archive

Answer (score 0):

[Renee](https://metacpan.org/author/RENEEB) pointed me to how `Tapper` makes it: https://metacpan.org/source/TAPPER/Tapper-TAP-Harness-4.1.1/lib/Tapper/TAP/Harness.pm#L273

Quite some effort to read an archive though...